# Adding a header above a autocomplete field?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, autocomplete, header

I would like to have a fixed header above the results shown for the autocomplete field which categories which part the result is from? The dropdown may not be a google data dropdown, it could be a normal autocomplete with a fixed header inserted.

May I know, how can I do it? Anyone can help me?

Code:

```
<script>

function initialize() {

    map = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(

    (document.getElementById('add')), {
        types: ['code']

    });   
}
</script>
<label>Address</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="input-group">
     {!! Form::hidden('pickup_lat', old('pickup_lat'), ["class" => "form-control"]) !!}
      {!! Form::hidden('lon', old('lat')!!}
     {!! Form::text('pickup_address', old('add'), "id" => "add"]) !!}
</div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

I had tried :

http://jsfiddle.net/ud3sh/v2Agq/4/

but it just shows the autocomplete result without the header

Comment: Where is your code? Have you tried to do this yourself, if so what issues did you walk into?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Google supports this feature. If you check the [Places search box guide and sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) you will see that there's no such thing.

However you are always free to make your own implementation out of your own toolbox.